# Fantastical: how to add alerts/reminders in text

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, reminders

I'm a big Fantastical fan, but I can't work out the syntax to add a reminder/alert to a new event:
For example:

> Lunch with John at 12:00, alert 15 min before

should give an event with the title "Lunch with John", at 12 o'clock today, and add an alert 15 min before. But it doesn't :)
I tried a lot of different combinations to no avail.

According to some blog post this should be working:
http://flexibits.com/blog/2012/05/1-3-add-reminders-to-fantastical/

Any clue anyone?

Thanks!

Comment: Confusion, confusion... The original question wants to set an alarm 15 min before the event. The answer cites the help pages that show how to create 'reminders'. This is not the same thing. Reminders are reminders, alarms are attached to calendar entries (which are not reminders). So I think it is not currently possible to write something into FantastiCal that translates into an alarm. Very sad! Anybody who thinks I am wrong: please share you knowledge, I would LOVE to know how to type alarms into FantastiCal... Cheers,
Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From [the same blog post](http://flexibits.com/blog/2012/05/1-3-add-reminders-to-fantastical/):*

> If you’d like to force Fantastical to create a reminder regardless of what you enter, you can start a sentence with “**reminder**”, “**todo**”, “**task**”, or “**√**” (<kbd>⌥ option</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>).

Also…

> You can quickly set the priority of a new reminder by adding exclamation points to the end of your reminder. More exclamation points will increase the priority of the reminder.

Comment: this doesn't accomplish what the question asked about, which is the syntax for setting alerts